# How to create a Trigger that contain some complex statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I use sqlite .

This is my table structure：

```
user_name | user_password
----------------------------
user1     | password1
user2     | password2
```

I want that when i insert a user ,first determine the user whether exist.

```
if exist 
   only update password
else
   insert user's name and password
```

So , how to create a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

With this particular schema you don't need a trigger. You can just use [`INSERT OR REPLACE INTO`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) syntax.

```sql
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO users (user_name, user_password) 
VALUES ('user1', 'new_password');
```

Note: make sure that you have a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint on `user_name` column.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8b6aa/1)** demo

Comment: @TangMonk Then just create a unique constraint on that column. Otherwise (meaning if user_name is not unique) how do you suppose to update a password???